# Can and should I use sbt and sbt-native-packager for non Java or Scala specific packaging of an RPM?

Tags: ant, sbt, sbt-native-packager

Like I could using Ant?

I don't have to compile sources or create jars to make the RPM.

If this is a good approach?

How to I use sbt without language specific features?

Comment: Checkout: https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the use case?

Comment: The question was in the context  of a closed source product. I needed a rpm for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Convention over configuration" is speaking:

*You could, but that would require reconfiguring lots of tasks and settings to meet your requirements and would likely not offer much benefit.*